# pyqt5: How to hide placeholder when widget is not enabled?

Tags: python, pyqt5, placeholder, qwidget

Simple solution may be:

```
self.placeholder_text = "......."
...
...

#trigger the following code when enabled state of self.widget_name is changed

if(self.widget_name.isEnabled()):
     self.widget_name.setPlaceholderText(self.placeholder_text)
else:
     self.widget_name.setPlaceholderText("")
```

But i have a lot of QLineEdit widgets, so i searching a solution to grap all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to cycle through all QLineEdit children:

```
for lineEdit in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    if lineEdit.isEnabled():
        lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(self.placeholder_text)
    else:
        lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("")
```

But that's probably not a good approach, as you have to constantly check for *all* widgets, and there might be some line edits for which you don't want this behavior.

A better solution could be to subclass the line edit and override its [`changeEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#changeEvent):

```
class MyLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._placeholderText = self.placeholderText()

    def setPlaceholderText(self, text):
        self._placeholderText = text
        if self.isEnabled():
            super().setPlaceholderText(text)

    def changeEvent(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnabledChange:
            super().setPlaceholderText(
                self._placeholderText if self.isEnabled() else '')
        return super().changeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox('Toggle enabled')
    layout.addWidget(checkBox)
    checkBox.setChecked(True)
    lineEdit = MyLineEdit(placeholderText='placeholder')
    layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
    checkBox.toggled.connect(lineEdit.setEnabled)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The above code works both for line edits created with the `placeholderText` added to the constructor (like in the example) and with promoted widgets used in Designer.

Alternatively, you can add an event filter to all line edits for which you want to enable this feature.

```
        self.widget_name.installEventFilter(self)
        self.some_other_widget.installEventFilter(self)
        # ...

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (isinstance(source, QtWidgets.QLineEdit) and 
            event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.EnabledChange):
                source.setPlaceholderText(
                    self.placeholder_text if source.isEnabled() else '')
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```